# Why is $\sqrt{T^*T}$ self-adjoint?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

> Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator over some Hilbert space $H$.
>
> Since $T^*T$ is a positive operator, it has a square root. Let $R=\sqrt{T^*T}$. Prove that $\forall u\in H, ||Ru||=||Tu||$.

Here's my approach:

$$||Tv||^2=\langle Tv,Tv\rangle=\langle T^*Tv,v \rangle = \langle R^2v,v \rangle= \langle Rv,R^*v \rangle$$

It would be convenient to have $R^*=R$, but I don't see why that should hold. Obviously $T^*T$ is self-adjoint, but why should its square root be self-adjoint as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a positive operator $A$, $\sqrt{A}$ is *defined* to be the unique *positive* square root of $A$.

The uniqueness and existence of such an operator is covered in most functional analysis texts.

Comment: $R^2=T^*T \implies (R^*)^2=T^*T$ and by uniqueness of the square root, $R^*=R$ ?

Comment: When *you* say "by the uniqueness of the square root", what do *you* mean by a square root?  If you mean $R = \sqrt{A}$ iff $R^2 = A$, then $R$ will **not** generally be unique.

Comment: Well, since $T^*T$ is a positive operator, the square root is unique, isn't it ?

Comment: The *positive square root* is unique.  Note at the very least that we would have to discount $-\sqrt{T}$ as a possibility.

Comment: By your definition, $\pm I$ are both "square roots" of $I$, and there are infinitely more.

Comment: You're right, I omitted the word positive everytime I've been referring to the square root, thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: The word "positive" is normally omitted.  However, it is implied.